# How to freeze a thread and notify it from another?

Tags: multithreading, rust, wait, notify

I need to pause the current thread in Rust and notify it from another thread. In Java I would write:

```java
synchronized(myThread) {
    myThread.wait();
}
```

and from the second thread (to resume main thread):

```java
synchronized(myThread){
    myThread.notify();
}
```

Is is possible to do the same in Rust?

Comment: Note that using `wait()/notify()` without a `while` loop on a shared flag is a bad idea - `wait()` may stop waiting without `notify()` being called, this is known as a spurious wakeup. Using specialized primitives like `CountDownLatch` or `Exchanger<Void>` would be much better; it would be very similar to channels in Rust in the answers below.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Using a channel that sends type `()` is probably easiest:

```
use std::sync::mpsc::channel;
use std::thread;

let (tx,rx) = channel();

// Spawn your worker thread, giving it `send` and whatever else it needs
thread::spawn(move|| {
    // Do whatever
    tx.send(()).expect("Could not send signal on channel.");
    // Continue
});

// Do whatever
rx.recv().expect("Could not receive from channel.");
// Continue working
```

The `()` type is because it's effectively zero-information, which means it's pretty clear you're only using it as a signal. The fact that it's size zero means it's also potentially faster in some scenarios (but realistically probably not any faster than a normal machine word write).

If you just need to notify the program that a thread is **done**, you can grab its join guard and wait for it to join.

```
let guard = thread::spawn( ... ); // This will automatically join when finished computing

guard.join().expect("Could not join thread");
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use [std::thread::park()](https://doc.rust-lang.org/nightly/std/thread/fn.park.html) and [std::thread::Thread::unpark()](https://doc.rust-lang.org/nightly/std/thread/struct.Thread.html#method.unpark) to achieve this.

In the thread you want to wait,

```
fn worker_thread() {
    std::thread::park();
}
```

in the controlling thread, which has a thread handle already,

```
fn main_thread(worker_thread: std::thread::Thread) {
    worker_thread.unpark();
}
```

Note that the parking thread can wake up spuriously, which means the thread can sometimes wake up without the any other threads calling `unpark` on it. You should prepare for this situation in your code, or use something like [std::sync::mpsc::channel](https://doc.rust-lang.org/nightly/std/sync/mpsc/fn.channel.html) that is suggested in the accepted answer.

Answer (score 2):

There are multiple ways to achieve this in Rust.

The underlying model in Java is that each object contains both a mutex and a condition variable, if I remember correctly. So using a mutex and [condition variable](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/sync/struct.Condvar.html) would work...

... however, I would personally switch to using a channel instead:

- the "waiting" thread has the receiving end of the channel, and waits for it
- the "notifying" thread has the sending end of the channel, and sends a message

It is easier to manipulate than a condition variable, notably because there is no risk to accidentally use a different mutex when locking the variable.

The [`std::sync::mpsc`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/sync/mpsc/) has two channels (asynchronous and synchronous) depending on your needs. Here, the asynchronous one matches more closely: [`std::sync::mpsc::channel`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/sync/mpsc/fn.channel.html).

Comment: Note that with a channel you can have only one waiting thread. If you need to wait in multiple threads and launch all at the same time, channel is not good for that.

Comment: @MikkoRantalainen: A MPSC channel wouldn't, indeed. A broadcast channel would work, though the threads may not start _quite_ all together. For all threads to launch together the smallest latency you can get is an atomic & busy waiting... but that has other downsides.

Answer (score 2):

There is a [monitor](https://github.com/kirillkh/monitor_rs) crate that provides this functionality by combining `Mutex` with `Condvar` in a convenience structure.

(Full disclosure: I am the author.)

Briefly, it can be used like this:

```
    let mon = Arc::new(Monitor::new(false));
    {
        let mon = mon.clone();
        let _ = thread::spawn(move || {
            thread::sleep(Duration::from_millis(1000));

            mon.with_lock(|mut done| {     // done is a monitor::MonitorGuard<bool>
                *done = true;
                done.notify_one();
            });
        });
    }

    mon.with_lock(|mut done| {
        while !*done {
            done.wait();
        }
        println!("finished waiting");
    });
```

Here, `mon.with_lock(...)` is semantically equivalent to Java's `synchronized(mon) {...}`.