# Wake another thread periodically with Rust

Tags: multithreading, rust

Condvar in Rust is good for waking another thread, but in this case below, I don't really need the `true`, I just want to wake the other thread periodically

```
use std::sync::{Arc, Mutex, Condvar};
use std::thread;
fn main() {
    let pair = Arc::new((Mutex::new(false), Condvar::new()));
    let pair2 = Arc::clone(&pair);
    
    // Inside of our lock, spawn a new thread, and then wait for it to start.
    thread::spawn(move|| {
        let (lock, cvar) = &*pair2;
        let mut started = lock.lock().unwrap();
        // We notify the condvar that the value has changed.
        loop{
            *started = true;
            cvar.notify_one();
            std::thread::sleep(std::time::Duration::from_millis(20));
        }
    });
    
    // Wait for the thread to start up.
    let (lock, cvar) = &*pair;
    let mut started = lock.lock().unwrap();
    loop {
        started = cvar.wait(started).unwrap();
        println!("done");
    }
    println!("end");
}
```

Also, this example does not even work, I don't know why. It should wake the main thread every 20 ms.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to freeze a thread and notify it from another?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37964467/how-to-freeze-a-thread-and-notify-it-from-another)

Answer (score 0):

The reason this doesn't work is that you're holding the mutex while you sleep. The main thread is only woken up after it has been hit with `notify_one` and its mutex is lockable. But the spawned thread holds the mutex locked forever.

[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=03259ea2eb767f776635971f59961dd9)

In fact, you don't need the lock at all in your spawned thread and you could make it contain no data by constructing it as `Mutex::new(())`. However, if you do that, it is possible that your main thread hasn't finished one `loop` by the time the spawned thread finishes its sleep. The mutex ensures that when you call `notify_one`, the main thread is definitely waiting to be notified. If you want that behavior or not is up to you. With locking the mutex in the spawned thread, the main thread is woken up immediately if its previous loop took longer than one tick. Without the locking, wake-ups may be skipped and the next wake-up is aligned to the next tick.

But really, do what's in the answers @Finomnis suggested and use channels.

Comment: Do you think channel is good for waking something like 120 times per second?

Comment: and then having 20 channels that do this

Comment: You mean, one thread waking up 20 other threads, or 20 threads waking up one thread? Also, "every 20 ms" is not the same as "120 times per second".

Comment: @GuerlandoOCs No idea. I don't even know why you want to wake up a thread every 20 ms with a different thread. You could just have the main thread track how long it needed for the iteration of the loop and then sleep the rest of the time. Maybe you should post a different question that asks about what you actually want to do, or we could [chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/62927/rust) about it.